# MySQL function fails in main server but works in localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I have a MySQL function as below, but it is generating an error:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE image1 VARCHAR(250);
select case when
    (
        select COUNT(*)
        from profile_images
        where building_id = bid
        and contractor_id = cid
    ) > 0
    then (
        select distinct (image)
        -- into image1
        from profile_images
        where building_id = bid
             and contractor_id = cid limit 1
    ) else (
        select distinct (image)
        -- into image1
        from profile_images
        where contractor_id = cid limit 1
    )
END into image1;
RETURN image1;
END
```

The actual error shown by MySQL is  #2014 - *Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now*.

Comment: Did you read the manual? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: yes. i just invoked the function from my-sql query window but still fails

Comment: In that doc mentioned about cursor but i dont know how to deal with cursor

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake.wrong parametername passed to the function.Thank you very much  Arvindh Mani.

Comment: If my formatting edit on your question was helpful, please accept it so that it becomes permanent.